# Insert After/Before Into Sorted LinkedList Big O Complexity

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, linked-list, binary-search-tree

In c# we have LinkedList library,which has some useful methods. One of is AddAfter/AddBefore methods. I think in sorted LinkedList it is O(log(n)) complexity, if it uses binary search;

Am I right or can you explain more accurate

Comment: Binary search can be used only on sorted collections, and linked list complexity in insert (except insert first) is O(n)

Comment: The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzf8sxa0.aspx) tell you the complexity is O(1).

Comment: yes, insert in collection it is O(1), but if you want to insert after specific value, what would be complexity? for example: SortedLinkedList: [2, 5, 7, 11, 14], I want to insert 8, basically after 11

Comment: @Lee but It is not sorted

Comment: @Boo why is it O(n) can you explain? If I do binary search

Comment: So you want to know how you can find the node to insert before/after in O(log(n)) time? You can't perform binary search directly on a linked list.

Comment: @user746499 the answer of Xanatos is what I meant with all the details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AddBefore` and `AddAfter` accept as the first parameter a `LinkedListNode<>` that is the node before/after which the new node will be added. This operation is `O(1)`.

Traversing (enumerating) the `LinkedList` is a O(n) operation, because to see the xth node you have to traverse x-1 nodes. You can't binary search a `LinkedList` because you can't access directly the xth element without traversing it.

So if you want to add a new node to a `LinkedList` that you are keeping ordered, first you have to traverse it to find the "right" position where to insert the new element (a O(n) operation), then you have to insert it by using `AddBefore` or `AddAfter` (a O(1) operation). The composite complexity is clearly O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the implementation. These two methods have nothing to do with search. So, it's O(1)

```
public void AddAfter(LinkedListNode<T> node, LinkedListNode<T> newNode) {
    ValidateNode(node);
    ValidateNewNode(newNode);
    InternalInsertNodeBefore(node.next, newNode);
    newNode.list = this;
}  

public void AddBefore(LinkedListNode<T> node, LinkedListNode<T> newNode) {
    ValidateNode(node);    
    ValidateNewNode(newNode);                        
    InternalInsertNodeBefore(node, newNode);
    newNode.list = this;
    if ( node == head) {
        head = newNode;
    }
}

private void InternalInsertNodeBefore(LinkedListNode<T> node, LinkedListNode<T> newNode) {
    newNode.next = node;
    newNode.prev = node.prev;
    node.prev.next = newNode;
    node.prev = newNode;            
    version++;
    count++;
}
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs

Comment: Yes I know that it is O(1) in unsorted LinkedList, but what about in sorted one?

Comment: Sorted or not doesn't matter because it will never search.